Is there a Gödel sentence for every model?
Gödel’s first incompleteness theorem states that in a formal system of arithmetic there is at least one formula that can be neither proven or disproven within that system.
The Gödel sentence is an example of such a unprovable formula. It is (implicitly) about natural numbers where it is (indirectly) true (although unprovable). As the system is a first-order logic system we can't restrict models of it. According to the completeness theorem there is at least one [nonstandard] model where the Gödel sentence is false (therefore not universally true).
Does this imply (or is there any other reason to think) that the model where the Gödel sentence is false will also have its own "true" Gödel sentence, resp. that we can create a true Gödel sentence for every possible model?
In addition, was such a model, where the original Gödel sentence for natural numbers is false, discovered?

Gödel sentences belong to theories, not models. (That said, the theory $\sf PA + \lnot G_{PA}$ will have its own Gödel sentence... incidentally this theory will one-up PA and actually disprove its own Gödel sentence.)

Perhaps you just want to ask "in a model where the Goedel sentence is false, must there be some unprovable sentence which is true in this model?" The answer to this is yes: take the negation of the Goedel sentence. Your last sentence is a bit vague. Are you not happy with the construction from the completeness theorem?

@IzaakvanDongen Yes, this is exactly what I meant and your answer is perfectly obvious. Thanks!

Izaak van Dongen's comment is exactly right. However, at least for certain choices of "ambient theory" (such as $\mathsf{PA}$ or $\mathsf{ZFC}$) we can say something perhaps more exciting.
The important thing about $\mathsf{PA}$ is that for every finite $F\subseteq\mathsf{PA}$, we have $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\mathit{Con}(F)$. This is the reflection property of $\mathsf{PA}$. This may appear perilously close to implying (via Godel's 2nd) the inconsistency of $\mathsf{PA}$ itself, but in fact it does not; the saving grace is the fact that we cannot move the "for all $F$" inside the "$\vdash$." Set theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$ also has this property.
OK, so what? Well, let $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{PA}+\neg\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$.  By the reflection property and overspill, there is some $n\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}\models$ "The first $n$ axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$ are consistent, but the first $n+1$ axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$ are inconsistent." Note that $n$ is necessarily nonstandard. Let $T$ be (what $\mathcal{M}$ thinks is) the first $n$ axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$. Then from the perspective of $\mathcal{M}$ the theory $T$ is itself subject to Godel's incompleteness theorems, and in particular has a Godel sentence $G_T$ which ... is true!
There is some slipperiness here. Most significantly in my opinion is the fact that $G_T$ is not an actual sentence: since $n$ is necessarily nonstandard, $G_T$ is itself necessarily nonstandard. That is, while $\mathcal{M}$ "thinks" that $G_T$ is a finite string of symbols satisfying the usual grammatical rules, it doesn't make sense to ask "externally-to-$\mathcal{M}$" about the logical properties of $G_T$. But this is still neat!
(And if we run this argument in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, which has the reflection property and also can reason directly about structures and prove the Completeness Theorem, we get that every model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ contains a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. See this answer of JDH for more on that.)
